# How pass multiple array of arrays to another page using curl and get those values with api and insert into db in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, web-services, curl

i want to pass options and answers array to another page using curl and get those values in php.

```
 index.php
 $url = 'localhost/..(where i can post).php';
 $fields = array(
        'id' => "1",            
        'options' => array(1,2,3,4),
        'answers' => array(2,3,1,4),
        )
    );

 //url-ify the data for the POST
 $data= http_build_query($fields);

 //open connection
 $ch = curl_init();

 //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

 //execute post
 $result = curl_exec($ch);
  echo $result;

 //close connection
 curl_close($ch);

 ?>



   db
   answers
   id|option_id(from options array)|answers(from answers array)
```

questions and answers are linked like 1 for 1 and 2 for 2. How can i pass and insert my db in php using web api. i find error while getting the all answers and options in another page and insert.

Comment: no idea what you are asking

Comment: Do some work, ask for help when you're stuck. we not building it for you.

Comment: edited my question.